# Checking number of not empty strings in array of structure; assign NULL value to array of char in array of structure

Tags: c, arrays, function, struct, char

Function should returns a number of not empty strings in array of structures. After I enter a values, program stops working. 
And second question: How can I assign a null value to one *L* element in *Lancuch* structure array?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
    char L[100];
} Lancuch;

int funkcja5 (Lancuch[], int);

int main()
{
    Lancuch st[3];
    scanf("%s",&st[0].L);
    scanf("%s",&st[1].L);
    scanf("%s",&st[2].L);
    printf("%s\n",funkcja5(st,3));
    return 0;
}

int funkcja5 (Lancuch s[], int n)
{
    int i = 0, suma = 0;
    for(;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(strlen(s[i].L) > 0)
        {
            suma++;
        }
    }
    return suma;
}
```

Comment: did you use a  debugger to locate the bug?

Comment: @tristan: There are many bugs, but the crash is probably here `printf("%s\n",funkcja5(st,3));`.  It's all in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably the crash you are seeing.

```
printf("%s\n",funkcja5(st,3));
```

`funkcja` returns an int, yet you used the format specifier `"%s"`.  It should be `"%d"`.

Furthermore, the following expression:

```
&st[0].L
```

results in a `char (*)[100]`, i.e., a pointer to array of `char[100]`, not a pointer to char as `scanf` expects.  Arrays are not pointers, and taking the address of an array results in a pointer to an array. This may appear to work at times, but you are invoking undefined behavior.

What you wanted was for the array to degrade to a pointer to its first element, so...

```
scanf("%s",st[0].L);
/* and so on... */
```

Of course, you can still have a buffer overrun here.  `scanf` cannot be used safely; use `fgets` instead:

```
if(fgets(st[0].L, sizeof st[0].L, stdin)) {
    // successfully read
}
```

As for "assigning" a null value to an array, you can't; arrays are not assignable.  You can make them empty strings by simply making the first element the null terminator:

```
std[0].L[0] = '\0';
```

However, an array can never be null.  It seems like you are confusing arrays and pointers.

As an aside, turn your warning level up.  You should be getting errors on those `scanf` calls due to incompatibility between the format string and the input type.

Comment: When I change lines to `scanf("%s",st[0].L);` still I get an announcement from Windows "Program stop working" http://i.imgur.com/MGenOBe.png However, earlier there was "Process exited with return value 3221225477", now it's "... 255"

Comment: Oh, I couldn't notice wrong format specifier. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user3135351: No problem, but typically you would select this as the correct answer.